Can I cascade two different shift register?
I would like to drive multiple nixie tubes using shift register. I wonder that can I cascade two different shift registers to control them using arduino or another MCU? My plan is to connect DATA OUT of HV5522 to SER IN of TPIC6B595.


The other answer already covers daisy chaining shift registers, with considerations about potentially needing to add a buffer on the clock and latch line according to the length of the line.
Given the use of HV5522 and TPIC6B595 also need to consider the different supply voltages and digital signal voltage levels.
From the HV5522 datasheet Recommended Operating Conditions:



Parameter
Sym.
Min.
Max.
Unit




Logic Supply Voltage
VDD
10.8
13.2
V


High-level Input Voltage
VIH
VDD–2
VDD
V


Low-level Input Voltage
VIL
0
2
V



And  DC Electrical Specifications:



Parameter
Sym.
Min.
Max.
Unit
Conditions




High-level Output Data Out
VOH
VDD–1V
-
V
IDOUT = –100 μA


Low-level Output Voltage - Data Out
VOL
-
1
V
IDOUT = 100 μA



Which means the HV5522 logic supply voltage and input/output voltages are not 5 V  TTL or CMOS standard compatible, due to operating in the range around 12 V.
Whereas the TPIC6B595 datasheet Recommended Operating Conditions look 5 V CMOS compatible:



Parameter
Min.
Max.
Unit




VCC Logic supply voltage
4.5
5.5
V


VIH High-level input voltage
0.85
VCC
V


VIL Low-level input voltage
0.15
VCC
V



As a result, it will not be possible to directly daisy chain the HV5522 and TPIC6B595 devices, since logic level translators will also be necessary. If a 5 V MCU is used then depending upon which order the devices are daisy chained will affect the number of level translators needed. E.g.:

5 V MCU -> level translator -> 12 V HV5522 -> level translator -> 5 V TPIC6B595
5 V MCU -> 5 V TPIC6B595 -> level translator -> 12 V HV5522

If a 3.3 V MCU is used, it's output levels might be directly compatible with the input thresholds of the TPIC6B595.

Yes, daisy chaining shift registers that way is commonly done and one of the reasons that they are such popular.
If this device gets bigger, you might have to add a buffer to the clock line and the latch line (because that needs to drive all shift registers, and all the long lines leading to them). At speeds at which you'd want to control Nixie tubes, it's very unlikely this will become necessary (you can basically drive the serial clock as slowly as you want, and latching will happen at most a handful of times per second).
